# Jmeter slaves nodes: one in same subnet and second in other subnet

Tags: jmeter, master-slave

I am using below command to execute the test using two slaves where one slave is in same subnet as master and second slave is in different region from Master machine.

`Jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -n -t 192.168.XX.XX:24001,127.0.0.1:24002 -o c:\Users\a106275\Desktop\result1.csv`

```
192.168.XX.XX: Slave in same subnet 
127.0.0.1:24002: Slave in different subnet
```

I am unable to see results from slave `192.168.90.XX` which is same region. Can you please help me understand how do I get the results from slave in same region?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [Special-Use IPv4 Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330)

   > **127.0.0.0/8** - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
   > loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
   > address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.
   > This is ordinarily implemented using only 127.0.0.1/32 for loopback,
   > but no addresses within this block should ever appear on any network
   > anywhere

   So double check available IP addresses on the machine, my expectation is that you should be using other interface instead (unless you have master and slave running on the same node)
2. Your command line is missing [`-R switch`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options), it should look like:

   ```
   Jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -n -t -R 192.168.XX.XX:24001,127.0.0.1:24002 -o c:\Users\a106275\Desktop\result1.csv
                                                      ^ mind this key
   ```

See the following reference material for more information:

- [Remote Testing](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)
- [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

Comment: jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -n -t  sample_1412.jmx -R 192.168.xx.xx:24000,127.0.0.1:24001 -o c:\Users\a10627537\Desktop\result1.csv   I have been using -R in command. I mistakenly did not add it while posting  it.  when I strat jmeter.bat and run the test  on same subnet machine 192.168.xx.xx i am able to get the results. However if initiate the jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 from command line and then run the test on same slave, results are not coming.

Comment: I need to run the test on slave in same subnet and different subnet together. I am able to receive the results from different subnet slave if I initiate master using jmeter -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 and i have established SSH tunneling as well for different subnet slaves.  My problem is when i want to run the test combination of slaves(same & different subnet), how should I invoke master?